# What is the universal property of the algebra of formal power series over a commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, formal-power-series

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. For every set $I$, $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ is the algebra of formal power series.

Suppose $\sigma:I\rightarrow J$ is a bijection. Ignoring topology, what is the canonical *algebra isomorphism* between $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ and $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(J)}}$?

For example, let $(\alpha_\nu)_{\nu\in\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ be an element of $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$, what should be the image of this element in $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(J)}}$?

**Edit:**

Since $\sigma$ is a bijection, there exists a monoid isomorphism $f:\mathbb{N}^{(I)}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{(J)}$ such that $$f\circ\delta=\delta'\circ\sigma,$$
where $\delta,\delta'$ are the canonical injections of $I\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{(I)}$ and $J\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{(J)}$, respectively. Now, from set theory, we know that the mapping
$$g:A^{\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}\rightarrow A^{\mathbb{N}^{(J)}},\,(\alpha_\nu)_{\nu\in\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}\mapsto(\alpha_{f^{-1}(\mu)})_{\mu\in\mathbb{N}^{(J)}}$$
is a bijection.

*Definition*: By $\mathbf{N}^{(I)}$ denote the subset of $\mathbf{N}^{I}$ consisting of sequences with finite support.

Comment: Why would you ignore the topology? The topology (or equivalently, the filtration given by the gradation) is essential. The image should be: replace each $i\in I$ (in the index) by its image in $J$. What else would it be?

Comment: @tomasz thank you for your help.–I am reading a book on algebra and the author makes no mention of topology. If we denote by $\bar{\sigma}$ the canonical mapping $\mathbb{N}^{(I)}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{(J)}$, do you suggest to send $(\alpha_\nu)_{\nu\in\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ to $(\alpha_{\bar{\sigma}(\nu)})_{\nu\in\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$? But this latter is not an element of $\mathbb{N}^{(J)}$..it is not even defined..

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote down the definitions of these objects. I'm kind of guessing here, since I'm not familiar with this notation, so I may be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @tomasz sure. I have now made an edit. Is the $g$ the canonical map I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, that works. I was thinking about the question in the title, though. I think the formal power series ring is a free object in an appropriate category (something like the category of complete filtered commutative $A$-algebras), similarly to the polynomial ring, but I can't quite work it out now.

Comment: The question in the body of your post is at best tangentially related to the title of the post.

Comment: @EricWofsey that's a fair point. My idea was to try to figure out the universal property from this example. In any case, the universal property of the algebra of formal series should allow me to derive the isomorphism between $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ and $A^{\mathbb{N}^{(J)}}$.

Comment: @tomasz It's still not clear to me how $g$ sends $\sum_{\nu\in\mathbf{N}^{(I)}}\alpha_\nu\prod_{i\in I}X_i^{\nu_i}$ to $\sum_{\nu\in\mathbf{N}^{(I)}}\alpha_\nu\prod_{i\in I}X^{\nu_i}_{\sigma(i)}$. This is what the author claims. Would you please clarify this for me? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @Falq: It's enough to check monomials, or equivalently, coefficient by coefficient. The coefficient at $X^{\sigma(\nu)}$ is by definition $a_{\sigma^{-1}\sigma(\nu)}=a_{\nu}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more common notation is $A[[\{T_i\}_{i \in I}]]$. If $\sigma : I \to J$ is a map (**Edit:** with finite fibers), it induces a unique continuous ring homomorphism $A[[\{T_i\}_{i \in I}]] \to A[[\{T_j\}_{j \in J}]]$ which extends the identity on $A$ and maps $T_i \mapsto T_{\sigma(i)}$. Thus, it maps a general power series
$$\sum_{\mu \in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}} p_{\mu} \cdot \prod_{i \in I} (T_i)^{\mu_i}$$
to the power series
$$\sum_{\mu \in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}} p_{\mu} \cdot \prod_{i \in I} (T_{\sigma(i)})^{\mu_i} = \sum_{\nu \in \mathbb{N}^{(J)}} \left(\sum_{\Large \mu \in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}, \, \nu_j = \sum_{\sigma(i)=j} \mu_i} p_{\mu}\right)\cdot \prod_{j \in J} T_j^{\nu_j}.$$
When you ignore the topology, uniqueness fails, and you need to verify that the above formula indeed defines a ring homomorphism.

The whole construction is compatible with composition (it defines a functor), so a bijection $I \to J$ gets mapped to an isomorphism $A[[\{T_i\}_{i \in I}]] \to A[[\{T_j\}_{j \in J}]]$.

Comment: Martin, sorry to bother you again..In the right hand side of the last equation, is the index set $\{\mu\in\mathbb{N}^{(I)}\ |\ \nu_j=\sum_{\sigma(i)=j}\mu_j,\,\forall j\in J\}$ supposed to be finite? I am not able to see this

Comment: Notice that $\mu_i \leq \nu_{\sigma(i)}$. From this finiteness easily follows.

Comment: This does not work for an arbitrary map $\sigma$; you need $\sigma$ to have finite fibers.  Imagine a power series $\sum_{i\in I} T_i$ in infinitely many variables and a map that wants to send every $T_i$ to the same $T_j$.

Answer (score 1):

I think @tomasz' deleted answer goes in a direction most appealing to me (at least by this point...), namely, to say that a "formal power series ring" $R[[\{x_i\}]]$ over a commutative ring $R$ (probably with identity) in variables $\{x_i:i\in I\}$ is a/the projective limit of quotients $R[\{x_i\}]/I_d$ of polynomial rings $R[\{x_i\}]$ by the ideals $I_d$ consisting of polynomials of total degree $>d$.

The projective limit characterization is that a map *to* the proj lim is given by a compatible family of maps to the limitands. A bijection of the index sets of the variables identifies the ideals $I_d$, etc.

Really, this amounts to an assertion that an isomorphism of index sets in the category of sets induces an isomorphism of corresponding formal power series rings (with fixed ring $R$).

In particular, and maybe this is an implicit question, the postulated *uniqueness* of the map to the proj lim, induced by a compatible family of maps to the limitands, shows that there is a unique self-map of that proj lim that respects all those maps. So, "unique up to unique isomorphism", with that latter qualification having some significance.

Comment: Thank you Paul! I went for Martin's because I am still not clear about projective limit side of the story. But this is a good answer because it's something I can try to understand next.

Comment: @Falq, glad it's helpful. I remember in my own trajectory, it took a while to appreciate the virtues of "characterization" rather than "construction"... :)