# Showing that the sum of a certain family of elements of a free module is defined

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\gamma:J\rightarrow K$ be a map between sets and $R$ be a commutative ring. Write $f,f'$ for the canonical injections of $J$ into $\mathbb{N}^{(J)}$ and $K$ into $\mathbb{N}^{(K)}$. Then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$h_\gamma:\mathbb{N}^{(J)}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{(K)}$$
such that $h_\gamma\circ f=f'\circ \gamma $.

Assume $x\in R^{\mathbb{N}^{(J)}}$. For each $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{(K)}$, how to prove that the sum $\sum_{\beta\in h^{-1}_\gamma(\alpha)}x_\beta$ is defined, i.e. that the set $\{\beta\in\mathbb{N}^{(J)}\ |\ h_\gamma(\beta)=\alpha \land x_\beta\ne 0\}$ is finite for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{(K)}$?

For each $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{(K)}$, I have tried unsuccessfully to show that there exists an injection from $\{\beta\in\mathbb{N}^{(J)}\ |\ h_\gamma(\beta)=\alpha\land x_\beta\ne 0\}$ to $\{k\in K\ |\ \alpha_k\ne0\}$. Is this a correct strategy?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this statement?  It is not true.

Comment: I suspect you may have not written the statement correctly, though.  As written it is not a question about free modules at all, since $R^{\mathbb{N}^{(J)}}$ is typically not a free module!

Comment: @EricWofsey you're right, it isn't a free module. Are you sure this statement is false? Have you a counter example?

Comment: @EricWofsey the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168219/what-is-the-universal-property-of-the-algebra-of-formal-power-series-over-a-comm?rq=1 says it is possible. Is it wrong?

Comment: The answer there is wrong; I've left a comment there.

Comment: @EricWofsey ah Ok. If $\gamma^{-1}(k)$ is finite, for every $k\in K$, how can I prove that $\sum_{\beta\in h^{-1}_\gamma(\alpha)}x_\beta$ is defined? I guess Im not sure how this additional assumption helps.

Comment: $h^{-1}_\gamma(\alpha)$ is finite.  Thinking of $\alpha$ as a formal finite sum of elements of $K$, each term of that sum can come from only finitely many different elements of $J$ by assumption.

Comment: thank you. please bear with me, I am still don't see it. We know that $h^{-1}_\gamma(\alpha)=\{\beta\in\mathbf{N}^{(J)}\ |\ \alpha=(\sum_{j\in\gamma^{-1}(k)}\beta_j)_k\}$. I understand that for each $\beta$ in this set, we have $\alpha_k=\sum_{j\in\gamma^{-1}(k)}\beta_j$ for each $k\in K$. But how does this allow us to conclude that $h_\gamma^{-1}(\alpha)$ is finite?

Comment: $\beta_j$ must be $0$ for all $j$ that are not one of the finitely many such that $\alpha_{\gamma(j)}>0$.  And for those finitely many $j$, $\beta_j$ must be at most $\alpha_{\gamma(j)}$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Last question, why is $\{j\in J\ |\ \alpha_{\gamma(j)}\ne0\}$ finite?

Comment: That is by definition of $\mathbb{N}^{(J)}$.

Comment: Super, thank you so much